# Integral domain having finite ideals

Tags: ring-theory

Let R be an integral domain with unity and let R has a finite number of ideals. Prove that R is a field.

Comment: If you had bothered to use the search tool, you would have found an answer to your question already. Please consider doing this next time and spare us a no-context question dump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If R is finite, then it is a finite field.

Suppose that R is infinite, let $x$ be an element of R. Consider $I_n$ the ideal generated by $x^n$.  Since the number of ideals of R is finite, there exists $n,m, n<m$ such that $I_n=I_m$. This implies that $x^n =ux^m$ and $x^n(ux^{m-n}-1)=0$. Since R is integral, we deduce that $ux^{m-n}=1$. ThuS $x$ is invertible.